# Conditionally Hide Code from the Compiler

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

So here's the problem.  I'm set to release an update soon for iOS that will address some problems in iOS 7.  In order to do this, I need to use some specific iOS 7 functions/types.  I've made absolutely certain that iOS 7 code will only be executed on iOS 7 and fallback to different code for pre iOS 7.  Of course, I'm not allowed to submit with the current Xcode beta, so I'm trying to compile with the current Xcode release.  However, I can't seem to find a way to disable this particular warning:

`Use of undeclared identifier '<Redacted>'.`

Does anyone know of a way to disable this warning using a `#pragma`.  I've tried a bunch of different ones including

`-w`, `-Weverthing`, `-Wall`

but nothing seems to work.

**UPDATE**
Answer: You can't, of course, because the compiler can't compile an identifier it knows nothing about.  My solutions was to simply create a `#define`:

`#define <redacted> 1`

**UPDATE 2**
The answer below actually made it much easier.  I had already created a `#define Xcode5Code(code, alt)` that allowed me to execute code blocks conditionally.  By modifying it using the solution by @maddy:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
    #define Xcode5Code(code, alt) code
#else
    #define Xcode5Code(code, alt) alt
#endif
```

This allows me to to easily hide blocks of code from the compiler by using:

```
Xcode5Code({
    //Code to be execute only with Xcode 5
}, {
    //code to be executed in previous versions of Xcode
})
```

The main benefit of using the `#define Xcode5Code` is that Xcode will auto-complete it for you, which is a lot easier than using the full `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000`, which Xcode won't auto-complete.

This won't actually distinguish between iOS 7 and pre iOS 7 devices.  It only distinguishes what version of iOS the current Xcode can handle.  To distinguish between iOS devices versions I use:

```
NSUInteger DeviceSystemMajorVersion(void) {
    static NSUInteger _deviceSystemMajorVersion = -1;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    });
    return _deviceSystemMajorVersion;
}
```

The above is Apple's code, by the way. To dance around the NDA a little, I'll say that this helps with laying out a root controller's view, because that depends on both the version of Xcode you're using AND the version of iOS that's on the device.  And if you're trying to manage beta's as well as production code, this can help a lot.  Once you can submit apps with Xcode 5, the `#define Xcode5Code` will no longer be necessary.

Comment: That's not a warning, that's an error. How do you want the compiler to manipulate an identifier it doesn't know about?

Comment: Is that a warning?  Looks more like an error.

Comment: @Mat  Ah... duh, of course.  Apparently I need more coffee today.  Yes, it's an error and of course I can't expect the compiler to compile something it knows nothing about.

Comment: I've got some warnings set to treat as errors and, of course, that isn't one of them.  It threw me off a little.

Comment: Using compiler preprocessor directives aren't runtime checks, meaning that the iOS7-specific code is not being compiled at all, and won't be run on iOS7 devices, which isn't what you said your goal was in the second sentence.

Comment: @Kitsune Yes, you're right.  I have another `#define` which returns the the current major OS version at runtime. I use that to run iOS7 code that won't be a problem compiled under Xcode 4.  I use the `#define iOS7Only` directive to only use that code if it will be a problem under Xcode 4.  This is very helpful in root controller view layout, which is about all I can say.  All this means I've poorly named my directives.  I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to compile your app with two difference versions of Xcode or two different Base SDK settings then you should use compiler directives:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000 // iOS 7.0 supported
    // iOS 7 code here
#else
    // Pre-iOS 7 code here
#endif
```

Do not use this for runtime checks. This solution is only to be used when you must compile your code with two different versions. An example would be you have added iOS 7 code but you still need to compile the code with Xcode 4.6. Using the compile directives allows you to "hide" the iOS 7 code from the compiler using the older Base SDK.

See the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the docs for more on this and proper runtime checks.