# Preprocessor and/or Macro way to check iOS SDK version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I am buliding a dark themed iOS 6 and 7 app. I understand I can call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` to make the iOS 7 status bar suit a dark color theme application.

The problem is I am going to submit my app to the App Store and currently Xcode 5 is not ready for that, so I have to use Xcode 4.6.x to do this task. However with Xcode 4.6, I am not able to compile the new method from iOS 7. I think I have to do something like ""if ios7"" then do `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` and reposition my application window.

I am trying to do this with `#ifdef` ... `#else`...
this code is `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` inside the `viewDidLoad`.

Could anyone help to understand how to use `#ifdef`... with the method in some functions.

Comment: I just answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404746/disable-clang-error-with-pragma/18406309#18406309

Comment: I just solve my problem. thanks

Comment: My friend, apple will not accept any build made by xcode version lower that 5. So try to use xcode 5 and later versions.

Answer (score 22):

While I'm not 100% sure I can fully answer this without breaching NDA, I'll do my best to point you in the right direction.

You need to use the `__IPHONE_*` #defines in Availability.h

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_6_0 && defined(__IPHONE_6_0)
  // iOS 6+ code here
#else
  // Pre iOS 6 code here
#endif
```

Please be aware that `#if` and `#ifdef` will determine what code is **compiled**, it is not a runtime detection mechanism.

You can easily access Availability.h by using Open Quickly and typing in Availability.

Comment: There is nothing in your answer that is covered by an NDA. Why would you think that? Only iOS 7 specific APIs are covered.

Comment: Surely the contents of Availability.h as supplied in the iOS 7 SDK is covered under NDA? Regardless this answer should be able to be adapted for iOS 7 easily without even looking at the header file. I +1'd and up-voted your other answer though :)

Comment: `iOS17` -- #if  __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >=__IPHONE_17_0 && defined(__IPHONE_17_0) ✌

Answer (score 2):

take a look to respondsToSelector

```
 [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:)]
```

Comment: This doesn't help. The compiler will still complain on the line that actually calls the method.

Comment: Not if the receiver is of type `id` or you use `performSelector:withObject:`. Anyway, the `#if` method above is probably tidier.