# Google Drive SDK modifications to run under Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-drive-api, deprecated

Google Drive SDK requires modification to run under Xcode 6 beta, primarily because of the following changes...

`NSGregorianCalendarIdentifier` is deprecated in iOS 8 in favour of `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian`,

and

`NSUndefinedDateComponent` is deprecated in iOS 8 in favour of `NSDateComponentUndefined`,

and

all references to `NSCalendarUnits` have changed so that the unique identifier of each key is moved from the front to the end. For example...

`NSMonthCalendarUnit` is deprecated in iOS 8 in favour of `NSCalendarUnitMonth`.

While I applaud these sensible changes, I had to run through a couple of classes to change the deprecated keys. This in itself is a five minute fix, and does not concern me at all.

**My problem: When I return to Xcode 5.1.1 to continue building "next releases", I must change these back to the deprecated keys.**

Rather than duplicate entire Xcode projects, is there a more frugal method that will manipulate the GTLDateTime header and implementation files to manage both scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with compiler directives.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000

// do Xcode 6 stuff

#else

// do Xcode 5 and earlier stuff

#endif
```

This will conditionally compile the code so that the new compiler won't complain about the deprecations and the old one won't complain about nonexistent symbols.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404746/conditionally-hide-code-from-the-compiler)